# "Use of undefined constant" error on PHP site

Tags: php

I have a site I am trying to setup on a new *Ubuntu 14.04 VM*, but get this error when trying to access any page other than the index page.  I've seen references for surrounding items in single quotes, but I'm not seeing where to do that.

**Error:**

> PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant HOSTED_LOCAL - assumed 'HOSTED_LOCAL' in /var/www/demo/config/config.php on line 7, referer: http://X.X.X.X/demo/

**This is the code referenced in the error:**

```
if(!HOSTED_LOCAL){
    // Mysql Database Time Zone Settings //
    define("DB_TIMEZONE", '+05:00');

    // PHP Time Zone Settings //
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried changing it to 'HOSTED_LOCAL'?

Comment: In `if(!HOSTED_LOCAL)` you are checking the value of a constant `HOSTED_LOCAL`. This PHP Notice is warning you that this constant was never defined anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is `defined`, try the following

```
if(!defined('HOSTED_LOCAL')) {
```

http://www.php.net/defined

Comment: I gave this a try and the error goes away.  I do get a 404 Not Found on any page other than index.php, this also happened before the change.  I can't seem to find any errors for that.

Comment: You probably need to enable mod_rewrite, or something along the lines of an .htaccess

Comment: You are correct.  I enabled mod_rewrite with the command "sudo a2enmod rewrite" and added <Directory /var/www/>AllowOverride All</Directory> to /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf